# Creating new sheets and renaming them in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013. I have the macro that adds a new sheet and renames it. But when I run the macro for the second time, it throws an error because there is a sheet with the name that was just created. For example, I create a sheet and name it Account, the next time when I run the macro I want it to be Account1 and next time Account2 and so on.

Comment: "I have the macro that adds..." We don't know what macro you're talking about. Show the macro you're using. Have you tried changing anything so the names aren't always the same? What have you tried, and how did that fail?

Comment: Hi Thx for replying, this is the code - Sheets.Add.Name = "Account". When I run the macro for the first time, it is adding a sheet and renaming it as Account. BUt when i re-run the macro, it throws an error as there is an existing sheet named Account. What i want is, when i run the macro every time keep naming it Account1, account2 and so on.. hope i am clear. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure will add a new worksheet and name it properly:

```
Sub AddWS()
    Const WS_NAME = "Account"
    Dim c
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet)
        Do
            .Name = WS_NAME & c
            If Err = 1004 Then
                c = c + 1
                Err.Clear
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: you can manage the base name applied to the newly created worksheet by editing the first line.

**UPDATE**

Based on your new requirement to be able to access the newest worksheet created at a later point by using the base name ('Account' in your question), please use this version of the above procedure:

```
Sub AddWS()
    Const WS_NAME = "Account"
    Dim c
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet)
        Do
            .Name = WS_NAME & c
            If Err = 1004 Then
                c = c + 1
                Err.Clear
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Newest_" & WS_NAME, .Name
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, later on when you wish to select that sheet, you can use this code:

```
Sheets([Newest_Account]).Select
```

Comment: one more question to go with this one, pls could you answer that too? Sheets("Control").Select 
Range("F14").Select
    Selection.copy   
    Sheets("Account").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
--------------------------
As you can see I am copying a cell from a Sheet called Control and pasting into the newly created sheet called Account. If a re-run the macro again, a new sheet Account1 would be created, so any way to change it dynamically? thx

Comment: The first time I run the macro - it would create sheet named Account and the above code would work. Second time I run the macro sheet Account1 would be created. Now what I want is, the above code to work for Account1? i.e Selection.copy Sheets("Account") should change dynamically according to the new sheet that was created. if newly created sheet is Account5, then that code should select the sheet Account5, hope i am clear.. thanks

Comment: @SaranyaSuresh Please see the update at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, see below, which assumes you want to create 10 new tabs, starting with Account1, and ending with Account10. It works by using the counter variable to count down from 10, and each time it creates the new tab, it simply appends the counter's value to "Account" for the sheetname.

```
Sub Sheet_Creation()

    Dim counter As Integer

    For counter = 10 To 1 Step -1
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Account" & counter
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Account" & Worksheets.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

The above macro will create new sheets named Account#, with # = the total number of sheets.

Comment: This is not want OP wanted. You are appending the total number of worksheets to the name. OP wanted numbers only if a worksheet already exists with the name used.